# Make Social Icons Clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching online for some instructions how to make social icons clickable but I can't seem to find the answer. I like to put in my blog some icons with codes like these:

```css
 .social-wrap {
          width: 325px;
          height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          margin: -25px 0 0 -162.5px;
        }
        .social-wrap button {
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          font-size: 1.25em;
          transition: color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-out, border-radius .25s ease-out;
          box-shadow: 0px 27px 73px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        }
        .social-wrap button:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
          border-radius: 50px;
          box-shadow: 0px 27px 45px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        }
        .social-wrap .facebook {
          color: #3b5998;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        .social-wrap .facebook:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #3b5998;
        }
        .social-wrap .facebook:active {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #3b5998;
        }
        .social-wrap .twitter {
          color: #00aced;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        .social-wrap .twitter:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #00aced;
        }
        .social-wrap .twitter:active {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #00aced;
        }
        .social-wrap .google-plus {
          color: #dd4b39;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        .social-wrap .google-plus:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #dd4b39;
        }
        .social-wrap .google-plus:active {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #dd4b39;
        }
```

```html
  <div class='social-wrap'>
    <button class='facebook'>
      <i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>
    </button>
    <button class='twitter'>
      <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
    </button>
    <button class='google-plus'>
      <i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i>
    </button>
 </div>
```

How can I make it clickable? I tried inserting button tags but it gives me some error " `Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.`". Please give me some idea how to do it. TIA

Comment: Need to add more code. And you're missing '{ }'

Comment: Hello Zapp, you mean the CSS code?

Comment: Yes. Add your code. Plus youre missing the opening and closing brackets { }

Comment: Hi Zapp, I've added the HTML and CSS codes...I'm not really familiar with the HTML code the one with "%button". I'm familiar with the basic HTML and CSS structuring.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just wrap the `<i>` tags in `<a>` tags with the href attribute set to the appropriate link:

```
<a href="your-link-here">
    <i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>
</a>
```

you can even wrap the buttons in the `<a>` tags if need them to be clickable as well.

Answer (score 1):

One easy fix is to surround the button by anchor tag `<a>` and add the `href` attribute of it.

```css
.social-wrap {
  width: 325px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -162.5px;
}

.social-wrap button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transition: color .25s ease-out, background .25s ease-out, border-radius .25s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 27px 73px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.social-wrap button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 27px 45px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.social-wrap .facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social-wrap .facebook:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.social-wrap .facebook:active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #3b5998;
}

.social-wrap .twitter {
  color: #00aced;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social-wrap .twitter:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00aced;
}

.social-wrap .twitter:active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00aced;
}

.social-wrap .google-plus {
  color: #dd4b39;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.social-wrap .google-plus:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

.social-wrap .google-plus:active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #dd4b39;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='social-wrap'>
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><button class='facebook'>
      <i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>
   </button></a>
   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><button class='twitter'>
      <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
    </button></a>
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><button class='google-plus'>
      <i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i>
    </button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose them in anchor tags instead of button tags, and then style the anchor tags to look like buttons.

```
<a class="facebook button" href="https://facebook.com/">
  <i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>
</a>
```

---

In the stylesheet change

`.social-wrap button` to `.social-wrap .button`

and

`.social-wrap button:hover` to `.social-wrap .button:hover`

(periods before the 'b' in 'button')